# How to add DataContact to WCF?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-client

I have created many class as my data class i.e:

```
 [DataContract]
public class pCity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string cityName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string provinceCode { get; set; }
}
```

I know if I put them into the WCF's svc.cs file or use them in WCF then it will be added and Silverlight side will see them from the Wcf Service Client's reference.

But I don't want my wcf file getting to large, so I store them into difference classes and in another class library project, reference it in Silverlight's Web Project.

Is there a quick way I can add them all into WCF (without doing the things I described above) so I can see them in Wcf Service Client's reference.

Thanks in advance.
King

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will never show up in a client's reference unless they are actually used by the service. That is, they must be either the type of a parameter, or else be the return type from an operation.

Comment: Right, as long as the service methods reference a DataMember class (which automatically brings in any classes the referenced class contains) it doesn't matter whether it is in the svc.cs file or in a separate cs file within the service project. It is usually best practice in Visual Studio to have a cs file per individual class.

Comment: So does that mean the only way I can use all of them is to make a function in wcf that uses each of the class as parameter?

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to use the same assembly in the client as in the service, then it doesn't matter.